# I can't find file `pgfutil-common-lists.tex'

Tags: installing, texlive

I am using texlive 2013, and just ran the following command to update the packages.

```
sudo ./tlmgr update  -all
```

After it finished, I tried to compile tex documents that uses `tikz` package as the following MWE shows:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
      aaaa
 \end{document}
```

Then pdflatex complains; it said:

```
 (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
 (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
 ! I can't find file `pgfutil-common-lists.tex'.
 l.556 \input pgfutil-common-lists.tex
```

The problem is that, **pgfutil-common-lists.tex** is indeed in the directory:

```
 /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/
```

Why is that? pdflatex should be able to find it, right?
I even download the [pgf package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) again, and replace the pgf directory in

```
 /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/
```

Nothing changed at all........... Any idea? Thank you for your critics.

%=====================================================================

Then followed the comments, I type the following command in the terminal:

1. `sudo mktexlsr` gives me `command not found`;
2. `mktexlsr` gives me:

   mktexlsr: /usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local: directory not writable.     Skipping...
    mktexlsr: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config: directory not writable. Skipping...
    mktexlsr: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist: directory not writable. Skipping...
    mktexlsr: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var: directory not writable. Skipping...
   mktexlsr: Done;
3. For`kpsewhich pgfutil-common-lists.tex`, nothing pops up.

Comment: run `sudo mktexlsr` and then `kpsewhich pgfutil-common-lists.tex`. Is there any output? By the way: I have no problem with TL2013

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like that your path setting is wrong. Try once

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:~/bin:$PATH
```

change `x86_64` if you do not have a 64 bit system. Then run again `sudo mktexlsr`
 If it works then add to your local `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:~/bin:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH
```

Comment: you should accept an answer if it helped. Otherwise it will be counted as unanswered.

Comment: I click the checkmark for your answer. Am I right? 0_0

Comment: @MelonTomato Yes, this worked. You know, this is exactly the way you are supposed to thank someone. :) The check mark is more important than *Thank you*.

Comment: Yeah, I got it :)  ^______________^