# ! I can't find file `pgfutil-common-lists.tex'. \input pgfutil-common-lists.tex

Tags: pgfplots, miktex, texmaker

I've recently run into the following error message that I have no idea on how to resolve:

> ```
> ! I can't find file `pgfutil-common-lists.tex'. \input pgfutil-common-lists.tex
> ```

It occurs when I use the `pgfplots` package. It showed up all of a sudden yesterday (even though previously it compiled fine with the `pgfplots` package) and I haven't done any changes to it. I've never had to input the `pgf-common-lists.tex` file before for it to work.

I am currently using MiKTeX with Texmaker on Windows 7. My latex files compile fine on other computers.

I have seen a similar problem answered here ([I can't find file `pgfutil-common-lists.tex'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163033/i-cant-find-file-pgfutil-common-lists-tex)) but I am on a Windows 7 machine and cannot follow the instructions given in the answer.

New error after I included the above file:

> ```
> ! I can't find file `pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex'
> ```

Solved: reinstalled miktex.

Comment: Did you interrupt an update while compiling a document?

Comment: the file is on ctan, but not in miktex.  ctan location: `http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/tex/generic/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex`

Comment: report the absence of the file, to the miktex list, too...

Comment: Thanks for the file @wasteofspace - i included it in the directory of my tex file but now it gives a new error: ! I can't find file `pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex'.

Comment: i don't think i interrupted an update @percusse - but i think i should reinstall the pgfplots package

Comment: @wasteofspace: Here in my MiKTeX installation it is included. Also the other missing file Demetris reported in his edit does exist here.

Comment: The files you report here as missing ones are both included in my MiKTeX installation. Both belong to `pgf`. So you should update this package (collection). It may be necessary for your situation, that you first should uninstall the old installation of `pgf`, but by default this would not be needed. Perhaps you installed as admin, but have to refresh the FNDB also _as user_ (if this is the case you will have to do this now and forever).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a localized problem that could be solved with an update of package `pgf` or an FNDB refresh as admin _and_ as user.