# "I can't find file `pgfutil-common-lists.tex'." after update

Tags: texlive

I've just did an update.

```
$ sudo tlmgr update --self
tlmgr: package repository http://sunsite.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no updates for tlmgr present.
tlmgr: no updates available
$ sudo tlmgr update --all
[...]
[108/109, 06:49/06:49] update: collection-pictures [1k] (32769 -> 33307) ... done
[109/109, 06:51/06:51] update: collection-publishers [1k] (32864 -> 33330) ... done
tlmgr: package log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
running mktexlsr ...

mktexlsr failed (status -1), output:

running mtxrun --generate ...

mtxrun --generate failed (status -1), output:

Can't exec "kpsewhich": No such file or directory at ./tlmgr line 679.
Use of uninitialized value $TEXMFSYSVAR in scalar chomp at ./tlmgr line 679.
Can't exec "kpsewhich": No such file or directory at ./tlmgr line 680.
Use of uninitialized value $TEXMFSYSCONFIG in scalar chomp at ./tlmgr line 680.
Can't exec "kpsewhich": No such file or directory at ./tlmgr line 681.
Use of uninitialized value $TEXMFLOCAL in scalar chomp at ./tlmgr line 681.
Can't exec "kpsewhich": No such file or directory at ./tlmgr line 682.
Use of uninitialized value $TEXMFDIST in scalar chomp at ./tlmgr line 682.
Use of uninitialized value $TEXMFDIST in concatenation (.) or string at ./tlmgr line 693.
Can't exec "kpsewhich": No such file or directory at /usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2785.
Use of uninitialized value $tmfsysconf in scalar chomp at /usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2785.
Use of uninitialized value $tmfsysconf in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2786.
Cannot open /web2c/updmap.cfg for writing: No such file or directory at /usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2928.
```

Then I run `mtxrun --generate` which seemed to work.

Then I've tried to compile [this file](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/tikz/landtagswahlen-in-bayern) and got:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
! I can't find file `pgfutil-common-lists.tex'.
l.556 \input pgfutil-common-lists.tex

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name:
```

When I enter `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex` it seems to work until it gets to `pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex` which it also doesn't find.

As [one other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163033/5645) with the same problem had problems with the path, I checked it (added breaks to make it easier to read):

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:
/usr/local/games
```

I don't know why TexLive is there 5 times, but that should not be a problem (?)

Before the update, I had pgfplot 1.09.

Can anybody please tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have a look to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163033/i-cant-find-file-pgfutil-common-lists-tex

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I saw this question. Wehn You look at my path, this should not be the same problem.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: I've just did run `sudo mktexlsr` and then `kpsewhich pgfutil-common-lists.tex` again and it worked ... very strange. And somehow my `sudo` PATH seems not to be the same as my usual PATH.

Comment: I guess this can be closed. Perhaps I should ask a question on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ why my sudo path is different from my usual path and how I can display the sudo path.

Comment: @moose Close as duplicate?

Comment: @Johannes_B I'm not sure about it. I did not get this problem again. What helped be in April 2014 was the question of [I can't find file `pgfutil-common-lists.tex'](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163033/5645), not the answer. However, the question title is so similar I guess it is a duplicate. I'll vote for "close as a duplicate".

Comment: @moose Voted to close as duplicate. We could of course close it as off-topic since it was an OS issue. Joseph can do it. But as a duplicate, it might be more helpful for others.