# Why is the pin's angle argument displayed as text?

Tags: nodes, labels

I'm completely stuck with the syntax of the command options `\node`

Here is my code line:

```
\node [circle,fill=blue,scale=0.5,pin=60:$q_0$] at (9+90:15*4/30) {};
```

And it displays the same as if I had written `pin=0:{60:$q_0$}`

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: I do not get the same output from the two versions.  What version of `tikz` do you have (use `\listfiles` at the beginning of your document to get this information)

Comment: Thanks for the help Andrew. version : 2.10 . the angle information is not token in account and is displayed and I can't figure it out. If you need the all code don't hesitate to ask but I am not sure it's very useful here.

Comment: Update to v 3.0.0

Comment: I'am afraid to do that. It seems to be a difficult task...

Comment: You should update you tex installation to include the new version.  This is usually not hard.

Comment: I've downloaded the PGF3.0.0 package but I don't know where I should unpack it because I've got 3 folders in `./Library/Tex/Root/` , `textmf-config`, `textmf-dist` and `textmf-var`. I work with a mac and TexLive 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer my own question because I think I have solved my problem. I met some difficulties to get there so if it can be used for other I'll explain in detail.

1/ I downloaded the PGF_3.0.0 package [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/).

2/ I unzipped it and save it on my desktop.

3/ I copy all the folders in the following directory : `/Desktop/pgf_3.0.0.tds/tex/generic`

4/ I paste (and replace) in the following directory : `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic`

Then I though it was good and I manage the PGF update from 2.1.0 to 3.0.0 but I got the following error : `I can't find file`pgfutil-common-lists.tex`

5/ I follow [those](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163033/i-cant-find-file-pgfutil-common-lists-tex) instructions and I did run this command `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin:~/bin:$PATH`

6/ Then I run `sudo mktexlsr` command and I get the following answer from the terminal :

```
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
```

(I did not follow the recommandation to add the 3 lines to the .bashrc because I was a bit lost...)

7/ Finally I opened TeXstudio and used a minimal document with the `\pgfversion`command and it displayed `3.0.0`.... YES !!!

8/ I tested my code line :

```
\node [circle,fill=blue,scale=0.5,pin=60:$q_0$] at (9+90:15*4/30) {};
```

And I get the result I looked for. Thank you all !

[image: mypic]

Comment: With TL 2013 you should be able to do `sudo tlmgr update pgf` to update `pgf` to v.3.0. Or use TeX Live Utility, if that is available (it may only be part of MacTeX though). Updating manually like this shouldn't really be necessary. Alternatively, you could install TL2014.

Comment: I tried to update like you that but, unfortunately, it did not work since the 2014 shows up... as least it's what I understood. And yes it was my last try, after that I'll install the 2014 (by the way : do not use chrome to download the 2014 package)

Comment: Hm, I thought it would work. Or perhaps I misremember, and PGF 3.0 didn't make it into TL 2013. Anyway, sorry about the noise.